# Where is my blocking code? I do not receive WebSocket message - Django Channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, python-asyncio, django-channels

So I have setup a simple web app with Django Channels, that handles some WebSocket connections.
It works almost perfect, however it does not receive messages, after I send messages initiated by another connection.

This is my consumers:

```
class CPConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.cp_id = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["cp_id"]
        self.cp = charge_point(self.cp_id, self)

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.cp_id, self.channel_name)

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, _):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.cp_id, self.channel_name)

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        print(f"CP {self.cp_id} sent: {text_data}")
        await self.cp.route_message(text_data)

    async def get_config(self, _):
        print(f"CP {self.cp_id} updates firmware")
        await self.cp.call(call.GetConfigurationPayload())
        print(f"CP {self.cp_id} sent response")


class CPUserConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.cp_id = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["cp_id"]
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, _):
        pass

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        print(f"User {self.cp_id} sent: {text_data}")
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(self.cp_id, {"type": "get.config"})
```

The CPConsumer isolated works perfect. It receives the messages, and routes them through the charge_point class. The charge_point object returns a message (it calls the consumers send method), and it is received by the client. So far so good.
Now I want the CPUserConsumer to initiate a message to the connection in the CPConsumer. The charge_point object needs to handle sending that messages.
So when the CPUserConsumer client sends a message, I can se that it is forward to the get_config method in the CPConsumer. The first print statement is printed. The call works fine, because my CPConsumer client receives the call, however when the client response, it is not received. The first print statement in the receive method is never printed.

**Why is not received at all?**
It is not received by a different CPConsumer object, neither an object in a different thread, because the print statement should have worked in all cases. Also as I understand the thread and the consumer object is kept alive throughout the WebSocket connection.
I suppose that I somewhere have blocking code that blocks the thread. This is the only explanation I could find (maybe I am wrong?).

**Where is the blocking code**
The code that handles the call in the charge_point class is these methods:

```
async def call(self, payload, suppress=True, unique_id=None):
        """
        Send Call message to client and return payload of response.

        The given payload is transformed into a Call object by looking at the
        type of the payload. A payload of type BootNotificationPayload will
        turn in a Call with Action BootNotification, a HeartbeatPayload will
        result in a Call with Action Heartbeat etc.

        A timeout is raised when no response has arrived before expiring of
        the configured timeout.

        When waiting for a response no other Call message can be send. So this
        function will wait before response arrives or response timeout has
        expired. This is in line the OCPP specification

        Suppress is used to maintain backwards compatibility. When set to True,
        if response is a CallError, then this call will be suppressed. When
        set to False, an exception will be raised for users to handle this
        CallError.

        """
        camel_case_payload = snake_to_camel_case(asdict(payload))

        unique_id = (
            unique_id if unique_id is not None else str(self._unique_id_generator())
        )

        call = Call(
            unique_id=unique_id,
            action=payload.__class__.__name__[:-7],
            payload=remove_nones(camel_case_payload),
        )

        validate_payload(call, self._ocpp_version)

        # Use a lock to prevent make sure that only 1 message can be send at a
        # a time.
        async with self._call_lock:
            await self._send(call.to_json())
            try:
                response = await self._get_specific_response(
                    call.unique_id, self._response_timeout
                )
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                raise asyncio.TimeoutError(
                    f"Waited {self._response_timeout}s for response on "
                    f"{call.to_json()}."
                )

        if response.message_type_id == MessageType.CallError:
            LOGGER.warning("Received a CALLError: %s'", response)
            if suppress:
                return
            raise response.to_exception()
        else:
            response.action = call.action
            validate_payload(response, self._ocpp_version)

        snake_case_payload = camel_to_snake_case(response.payload)
        # Create the correct Payload instance based on the received payload. If
        # this method is called with a call.BootNotificationPayload, then it
        # will create a call_result.BootNotificationPayload. If this method is
        # called with a call.HeartbeatPayload, then it will create a
        # call_result.HeartbeatPayload etc.
        cls = getattr(self._call_result, payload.__class__.__name__)  # noqa
        return cls(**snake_case_payload)

    async def _get_specific_response(self, unique_id, timeout):
        """
        Return response with given unique ID or raise an asyncio.TimeoutError.
        """
        wait_until = time.time() + timeout
        try:
            # Wait for response of the Call message.
            response = await asyncio.wait_for(self._response_queue.get(), timeout)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            raise

        if response.unique_id == unique_id:
            return response

        LOGGER.error("Ignoring response with unknown unique id: %s", response)
        timeout_left = wait_until - time.time()

        if timeout_left < 0:
            raise asyncio.TimeoutError

        return await self._get_specific_response(unique_id, timeout_left)

    async def _send(self, message):
        LOGGER.info("%s: send %s", self.id, message)
        await self._connection.send(message)
```

As i understand the call method ensures proper formatting, and then sends the message to the WebSocket client (_connection is the consumer object). It uses a asyncio Lock, which I suspected, however as I understand the lock only blocks, if another concurrent part is trying to use the same lock. So it should only block sending another call, not the consumer receiving a message. The next part raises the TimeOutError, so the code does not go beyond that. The _get_specific_response waits on a message appearing in a Queue, which never appears, because the object never receives the message from the WebSocket consumer, because the receive method of the consumer never receives the message. So I have 3 lines of code that I suspect:
`response = await self._get_specific_response(call.unique_id, self._response_timeout)`
`wait_until = time.time() + timeout`
`response = await asyncio.wait_for(self._response_queue.get(), timeout)`

The reason I suspect those is that the client receives the call from the line before those 3. And the next that happens is TimeOutError raised. I am pretty sure that it is not the second TimeOutError raising, due to the log message not appearing, and also the only message received have corresponding unique_id.

Is there anything I am missing?
What is wrong?

Appreciate all suggestions!

See the above for a thorough explanation